# Firebase callable + express?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

With `functions.https.onRequest(app);` it was possible to use express right away.

I'm wondering if it's possible to use `functions.https.onCall(...)` together with express in the same way?

`onCall(...)` seem to have a different signature but maybe there is still a way to keep using express while working with `onCall(...)` functions?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

No, it's not possible.  Callable functions force your endpoint to use a certain path, a certain type of input (JSON via POST) and a certain type of output (also JSON).  Express wouldn't really help you out, given the constraints of how callables work.  You can read about all the callable protocol details in the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable-reference).  You can see that callables abstract away all of the details of the request and response, which you would normally work with when using Express.

Comment: Thanks Doug. Is there a way then to organize functions to store them in their respective files (to avoid expansion of the main index.js)? Checking the following discussion currently, but maybe there is best practice for that: https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/issues/170#issue-234473557

Comment: Do whatever you find to be the best for your needs.  You have the full power of `require` to use as you see fit.

Comment: Thank you. I wish I had found this faster - it would've saved me a lot of time.

Answer (score 0):

What does work however is using onRequest and calling that... then you can use express like normal and have the simplicity of firebase callable on the client side...

then you can do your authorization like normal. For example with the following middleware:

```js
export const createFirebaseAuth = () => (req: express.Request, res: express.Response, next: express.NextFunction) => {
    console.log('Time: ', Date.now());
    const token = req.header('Authorization');
    if (!token) {
      res.status(400);
      res.send('Authtoken must be sent with a request');
      return;
    }
    admin
      .auth()
      .verifyIdToken(token.replace('Bearer ', ''))
      .then((v) => {
        req.user = v;
        next();
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        res.status(401);
        res.send(error.message);
        res.end();
      });
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Not WITH express but they can call the same functions...
they BOTH can exist as root...and express like whatever callable function exist at root (exports)...

So they can coexists...they also can call common functionality...such as a service layer...